# How do i write a group by query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting errors with PostgreSQL when am writing a group by query,
**am sure someone will tell me to put all the columns I've selected in group by**, but that will not give me the correct results.

Am writing a query that will select all the vehicles in the database and group the results by vehicles, giving me the total distance and cost for a given period.

Here is how am doing the query.

```
SELECT i.vehicle AS vehicle,
i.costcenter AS costCenter,
i.department AS department,
SUM(i.quantity) AS liters,
SUM(i.totalcost) AS Totalcost,
v.model AS model,
v.vtype AS vtype
FROM fuelissuances AS i 
LEFT JOIN vehicles AS v ON i.vehicle = v.id
WHERE i.dates::text LIKE '%2019-03%' AND i.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY i.vehicle;
```

If I put all the columns that are in the select in the group bt, the results will not be correct.

How do i go about this without putting all the columns in group by and creating sub-queries?

The fuel table looks like:

```
vehicle     dates           department      quantity        totalcost
1           2019-01-01      102             12              1200
1           2019-01-05      102             15              1500
1           2019-01-13      102             18              1800
1           2019-01-22      102             10              1000
2           2019-01-01      102             12              1260 
2           2019-01-05      102             19              1995
2           2019-01-13      102             28              2940
```

Vehicle Table

```
id      model       vtype
1       1           2
2       4           6
2       5           7
```

This is the results i expect from the query

```
vehicle     dates      department   quantity    totalcost   model   vtype
1           2019-01-01  102         12          1200        1       2
1           2019-01-05  102         15          1500        1       2
1           2019-01-13  102         18          1800        1       2
1           2019-01-22  102         10          1000        1       2
1           2019-01-18  102         10          1000        1       2
1                                   65          6500                 
2           2019-01-01  102         12          1260        5       7
2           2019-01-05  102         19          1995        5       7
2           2019-01-13  102         28          2940        5       7
1                                   45          6195
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the `fuelissuances`  table?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `i.vehicle AS vehicle` can be simplified to `i.vehicle`

Comment: the primary key is id, are you suggesting I group with it?

Comment: Your aggregation doesn't really make sense. Apparently there can be multiple departments per vehicle in the `fuelissuances` table - which of those departments should be returned? The same is true for the `costcenter` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't really make sense. Apparently there can be multiple departments and costcenters per vehicle in the `fuelissuances` table - which of those should be returned?

One way to deal with that, is to return all of them, e.g. as an array:

```
SELECT i.vehicle,
       array_agg(i.costcenter) as costcenters,
       array_agg(i.department) as departments,
       SUM(i.quantity) AS liters,
       SUM(i.totalcost) AS Totalcost,
       v.model,
       v.vtype
FROM fuelissuances AS i 
   LEFT JOIN vehicles AS v ON i.vehicle = v.id
WHERE i.dates >= date '2019-03-01' 
  and i.date < date '2019-04-01' 
  AND i.deleted_at IS NULL
group by i.vehicle, v.model, v.vtype;
```

Instead of an array, you could also return a comma separated lists of those values, e.g. `string_agg(i.costcenter, ',') as costcenters`.

Adding the columns `v.model` and `v.vtype` won't (shouldn't) change anything as the `group by i.vehicle` will only return a single vehicle anyway and thus the model and vtype won't change for that in the group.

Note that I removed the useless aliases and replaced the condition on the date with a proper range condition that can make use of an index on the `dates` column.

---

**Edit**

Based on your new sample data, you want a running total, rather than a "regular" aggregation. This can easily be done using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

```
SELECT i.vehicle,
       i.costcenter,
       i.department,
       SUM(i.quantity) over (w) AS liters,
       SUM(i.totalcost) over (w) AS Totalcost,
       v.model,
       v.vtype
FROM fuelissuances AS i 
   LEFT JOIN vehicles AS v ON i.vehicle = v.id
WHERE i.dates >= date '2019-01-01' 
  and i.dates < date '2019-02-01' 
  AND i.deleted_at IS NULL
window w as (partition by i.vehicle order by i.dates)  
order by i.vehicle, i.dates;
```

I would **not** create those "total" lines using SQL, but rather in your front end that display the data.

Online example: https://rextester.com/CRJZ27446

Comment: Nice!! the reason, why am asking this, is coz, I want to do a **UNION JOIN** for the query such that the first part will be doing the summation and the union will have the actual figures. so I've tried something like this and its asking for grouping them in the union too.

Comment: @GoodJohn: you don't need a union for that, use `group by rollup ()`

Comment: Please guide me on that coz am getting hilarious output.

Comment: @GoodJohn: please provide some sample data and the output you expect by [**editing**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55338266/edit) your question (do **not** put that in a comment). Ideally as a SQL script that does a `create table` and inserts the sample data using `insert into`

Comment: I have updated the question and shown the sample tables and results

Comment: @GoodJohn: that is something completely different than your initial question. The totalcost is now a running total not a "normal" aggregation any more

Comment: i wanted to you the first concept to get the second one, but it didn't work out, I thought this work like MySQL, my objective is to use the results in fpdf and loop through it while grouping it with the subtotal, that's why i am really hoping to see the grouping.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the groping as is in the sample output I defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a nested query to get those `SUM` you want inside that query.

```
SELECT i.vehicle AS vehicle,
i.costcenter AS costCenter,
i.department AS department,
(SELECT SUM(i.quantity) FROM TABLES WHERE CONDITIONS GROUP BY vehicle) AS liters,
(SELECT SUM(i.totalcost) FROM TABLES WHERE CONDITIONS GROUP BY vehicle) AS Totalcost,
v.model AS model,
v.vtype AS vtype
FROM fuelissuances AS i 
LEFT JOIN vehicles AS v ON i.vehicle = v.id
WHERE i.dates::text LIKE '%2019-03%' AND i.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Comment: The issue is grouping by, the summations even if I do it in this format, it will still ask me to group the remaining columns, and since those are different, the results will not be correct